# Javascript Delete doesnt trigger the Java backend

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs

I'm working on an app with React front end and Java backend (Spring boot). I have a button on the front end that is supposed to delete my entity. When I click it, it removes it from the UI but it still exists in the back end. When I refresh the page, it just re-appears again. Anyone notice what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The only place the backend and front end react is where I have the CrossOrigin in the backend. Is there some way to have this for every method? Or should I not even have to do this? Also, I think the backend API functions correctly. Everything works properly when testing via postman but nothing gets triggered from the react front end.

Edit 2: Lets say I post a beer via postman with an id of 3. So when I print the id in the console of the remove function, it is 3, but then I get the error DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/homebrews/$%7BbeerId%7D/ 404 (Not Found). Why does it translate the id from 3 to $%7BbeerId%7D? Are they technically the same thing?

**Homebrews.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './Homebrews.css';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Container, Table } from 'reactstrap';

class Homebrews extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      beers: [],
      isLoading: false
    };

    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    fetch('http://localhost:8082/homebrews')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({beers: data, isLoading: false}));
  }

  async remove(id) {
      await fetch('/homebrews/${id}', {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(() => {
        let updatedBeers = [...this.state.beers].filter(i => i.id !== id);
        this.setState({beers: updatedBeers});
      });
    }

  render() {
    const {beers, isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="Brew-Data">
        <h2>Homebrew List</h2>
        {beers.map((beer: Homebrews) =>
        <div key={beer.id} className="Square">
          <div key={beer.id} className="Data">
            <h2>{beer.beerName}</h2>
            <Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(beer.id)}>Delete</Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Homebrews;
```

**HomebrewController.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class HomebrewController {

@Autowired
private HomebrewService hbService;

@RequestMapping("/homebrews")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public List<HomebrewBeer> getAllBeers() {
    return hbService.getAllBeers();
}

@RequestMapping("/homebrews/{id}")
public HomebrewBeer getBeer(@PathVariable String id) {
    return hbService.getBeer(id);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/homebrews")
public void addBeer(@RequestBody HomebrewBeer beer) {
    hbService.addBeer(beer);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/homebrews/{id}")
public void updateBeer(@RequestBody HomebrewBeer beer, @PathVariable String id) {
    hbService.updateBeer(beer, id);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/homebrews/{id}")
public void deleteBeer(@PathVariable String id) {
    hbService.deleteBeer(id);
}
```

**HomebrewService.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HomebrewService {

@Autowired
HomebrewRepository repository;

public List<HomebrewBeer> getAllBeers() {
    List<HomebrewBeer> beers = new ArrayList<HomebrewBeer>();
    repository.findAll().forEach(beers::add);
    return beers;
}

public HomebrewBeer getBeer(String id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}

public void addBeer(HomebrewBeer beer) {
    repository.save(beer);
}

public void updateBeer(HomebrewBeer beer, String id) {
    repository.save(beer);
}

public void deleteBeer(String id) {
    repository.delete(getBeer(id));
}
}
```

**HomebrewRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;



public interface HomebrewRepository extends CrudRepository<HomebrewBeer, 
String> {

}
```

**Homebrew.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class HomebrewBeer {

@Id
private String beerId;
private String beerName;
private String beerStyle;
private String description;
private Boolean usedOnlineRecipe;
private double abv, originalGravity, finalGravity, specificGravity;

public HomebrewBeer() {}

public HomebrewBeer(String beerId, String beerName, String beerStyle, Boolean 
usedOnlineRecipe, String description,
                    double abv, double originalGravity, double finalGravity, 
double specificGravity) {

    this.beerId = beerId;
    this.beerName = beerName;
    this.beerStyle = beerStyle;
    this.usedOnlineRecipe = usedOnlineRecipe;
    this.description = description;
    this.abv = abv;
    this.originalGravity = originalGravity;
    this.finalGravity = finalGravity;
    this.specificGravity = specificGravity;
}

public void setBeerId(String beerId) {
    this.beerId = beerId;
}

public void setBeerName(String beerName) { this.beerName = beerName; };

public void setBeerStyle(String beerStyle) {
    this.beerStyle = beerStyle;
}

public void setUsedOnlineRecipe(Boolean usedOnlineRecipe) {
    this.usedOnlineRecipe = usedOnlineRecipe;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void setAbv(double abv) {
    this.abv = abv;
}

public void setOriginalGravity(double originalGravity) {
    this.originalGravity = originalGravity;
}

public void setFinalGravity(double finalGravity) {
    this.finalGravity = finalGravity;
}

public void setSpecificGravity(double specificGravity) {
    this.specificGravity = specificGravity;
}

public String getBeerId() {
    return beerId;
}

public String getBeerName() { return beerName; };

public String getBeerStyle() {
    return beerStyle;
}

public Boolean getUsedOnlineRecipe() {
    return usedOnlineRecipe;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getAbv() {
    return abv;
}
public double getOriginalGravity() {
    return originalGravity;
}

public double getFinalGravity() {
    return finalGravity;
}

public double getSpecificGravity() {
    return specificGravity;
}
```

Comment: Is your backend API successfully deleting the record?

Comment: can you post the homebrew class

Comment: Also you can pass the id to the delete function you dont have to pass the homebrew object

Comment: 1. Check browser network it calls the proper api url and it returns the 200. 2. U need to debug backend whether it works properly and deleting the value also U need to define 
@Transactional for DAO layer that removes the data

Comment: So my backend API works properly, I've tested it using postman and its fine. But when I try to delete from the front end, it does not work. I will also post the Homebrew class now.

Comment: Update: I changed the method in the js file from 'DELETE' to 'POST' and the same thing happened. This leads me to believe that something actually may be wrong with my backend api, not sure though.

Comment: Did you try to use Fiddler? It might help you pin point the issue (param no being sent sent, error 500 etc ...)

Answer (score 2):

You got incorrect [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax here:

```js
await fetch('/homebrews/${id}', {
```

So change above to:

```js
await fetch(`/homebrews/${id}`, {
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is this not what I have currently? Sorry, just trying to clarify!

Comment: @alexaggs backquote is `, so that's not what you have currently. However I don't really know why you should have, that's probably not the issue.

Comment: \`/homebrews/${id}\` , notice the small difference in quotes. This way the template parameters will be replaced. With single quotes this won't happen. If you would log your incoming id server side you'll see it will probably be `${id}`